# aspnet EnableCDN feature configuration

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to implement ScriptManager EnableCdn feature. Until now and after some research I have this code.

in my Global.asax file

```
 void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs on application startup
        // map a simple name to a path
        ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition("jQuery", new ScriptResourceDefinition
        {
            Path = "~/js/libs/jquery/jquery.js",
            DebugPath = "~/js/libs/jquery/jquery.js"
            ,
            CdnPath = "http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js",
            CdnDebugPath = "http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"


        });

        ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition("Twitter", new ScriptResourceDefinition
        {
            Path = "js/libs/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js",
            DebugPath = "~/js/libs/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"
            ,
            CdnPath = "http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js",
            CdnDebugPath = "http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"

        });
    }
```

In my scriptmanager :

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="Sm" runat="server" LoadScriptsBeforeUI="true" EnableCdn="true" EnableCdnFallback="true">
```

As you can see I set the path for the cdn's and paths to local files. When I test without an internet connection it dosen't fallback to the local files. (still try to load from cdn )
I'm misunderstand the concept of this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, after some searching on the web I found this [article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CDNsFailButYourScriptsDontHaveToFallbackFromCDNToLocalJQuery.aspx) that explains the concept well. Shows the configuration to use and how to use with and without aspnet 4.5.

I hope this helps someone out there